After loading a userform, the first click on a listbox does not select the clicked item
After loading a userform, the first click on a listbox does not always result in the clicked item being selected. It seems to take 1 click to first wake-up the listbox and a 2nd click to start selecting items as normal. This can also affect additional listboxes on the same userform.
I want the first click on a listbox to always register and result in the clicked item being selected.

In the Userform Initialization event, looping through all controls on a userform to run the SetFocus event forces all controls to also complete initialization, "waking" them up so that the first click by a user on any listbox will always register and the clicked item will be selected.
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim c As Control      

    For Each c In Me.Controls
        c.SetFocus
    Next c

End Sub


This works for me when a multicolumn ListBox is clicked, to get the text in the second column of the selected item.
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    MsgBox ListBox1.Column(1)
End Sub

Or, this one to get the text in the first column whether the ListBox is multicolumn or not;
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    MsgBox ListBox1
End Sub

